# Use variable in jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have a dial gauge chart using JQuery as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {
                    var value1 = 15000;
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'gauge',
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBackgroundImage: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: 0,
                            plotShadow: false
                        },
                        pane: {
                            startAngle: -90,
                            endAngle: 90,
                            background: null
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            gauge: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                dial: {
                                    baseLength: '0%',
                                    baseWidth: 5,
                                    radius: '100%',
                                    rearLength: '0%',
                                    topWidth: 1
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        // the value axis
                        yAxis: {
                            labels: {
                                // enabled: true,
                                distance: 20
                            },
                            // tickPosition: 'outside',
                            tickPositions: [0, 15000, 25000, 50000],
                            minorTickLength: 0,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 50000,
                            plotBands: [{
                                from: 0,
                                to: 15000,
                                color: 'rgb(239, 19, 19)',
                                thickness: '30%'
                            }, {
                                from: 15000,
                                to: 25000,
                                color: 'rgb(255,99,71)',
                                thickness: '30%'
                            }, {
                                from: 25000,
                                to: 50000,
                                color: 'rgb(0,128,0)',
                                thickness: '30%'
                            }]
                        },
                        series: [{
                            data: 25000
                        }]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

for fixed values this code works fine. However, I want to pass a variable in one of the inputs - `var value1 = 15000;`data:value1`

It is not taking the variable as input. is there any way I can make it dynamic?
as the variable is defined above and I want to use the same for the field "data"

Comment: There is no reason that `data: value1` shouldn't work, you probably just had a typo when you tried it out. Did you get an error in the JS console?

Comment: Error says - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then your problem is with your server code, and not jquery.

Comment: It worked when I deleted few references like js files which are not present. However, I actually need to get the data from service. So I added a viewbag in my application    var value1 = '@ViewBag.testValue'; I am not getting any error and nor the required result ( I have data in ViewBag.testValue)

Comment: Ok, I used   var value1 = parseInt('@ViewBag.testValue'); and it worked. Thank you guys!